# chatter files-lookup relationship

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

Can we create a lookup relationship to chatter files?

i have file id with with me and was trying to store it in an object.so thought of creating a field which has a lookup relationship to chatter files.but couldnt get the correct object.anyclue?

Comment: What about creating a Chatter FeedItem for the file on the object's record feed? This would associate the file with the record through the feed.

Comment: I want the file ids stored,so as to download later.so its like a download cart.

Answer (score 1):

Chatter Files are represented by the ContentVersion object (one record per version, all having a common ContentDocumentId)

The RelatedRecordId on (ContentPost) FeedItem is a lookup to the ContentVersion record which holds the Chatter File uploaded as part of the FeedItem.